# Eclipse not showing Pydev in Preferences

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7

After installing Eclipse and python I am not able to see Pydev on eclipse. When I try to install eclipse again it is showing as duplicate location.

Comment: How did you installed Eclipse, via repositories or download from eclipse.org? Which version? How did you installed Pydev?

Comment: Installed both from Ubuntu software center, Eclipse Indigo, Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse on Ubuntu (correct for 13.10) can not properly use plugins installed in the user's home directory. If you need PyDev or any other plugins not provided by Ubuntu, your only choice is to install it manually:

1. Uninstall Eclipse from Ubuntu.
2. Go to Home Folder, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Delete the *.eclipse* folder.
4. Reinstall Eclipse with [this](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) link.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you installed pydev with wrong version. remember check your java version(by typing java -version in console). if it says 1.6.X, then you should NOT check "Show only the latest versions of available softerware" option in the first popup window after "Help->Install New Software" clicked. by uncheck that option, you will see a long list versions of pydev, pick 2.8.2. it will work well with your current java version. btw, if your java version is above 1.7, pydev's version should be above 3.0.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Dowload Newest Eclipse
2. Follow this guide to install pydev plugin:
   http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html
3. open"preference" and search "pydev"

Or

You can use "Aptana Studio"

Comment: I followed as it was mentioned in the link above. but again Python is not showing in preferences.

Comment: I tried everything I know but it is still no use. How can i remove eclipse from my computer completely so as to start fresh installation again.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Help/Install New Software..." and instead of putting pydev link put this one http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install which is Aptana Studio that has pydev.

I've tried "Help/Install New Software..." quite a few times with http://pydev.org/updates but it haven't brought pydev into life. Eclipse would complain that pydev has been installed, but still would call gedit for .py files and there's no pydev in Window/Prefferences. I was already going to switch to something else, like PyCharm, but then gave it a try with Aptana Studio and i got my PyDev installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Pydev correctly, you should see an entry in Eclipse under Window -> Preferences:
[image]

Once there, go to Interpreter - Python, it should see all you python 2.7 libs automatically. If not click on the Auto Config button.

EDIT: ok i understand now. How did you installed Pydev? I simply went to Help ->Eclipse MarketPlace, then typed pydev on the search. In my case it's showing update because i already have it installed. It should be Install for you. Also i'm using Eclipse Java EE Juno 4.2 which i downloaded the binary from eclipse.org[image]

Comment: I agree with you but in the preferences option I am not getting the option of Pydev. I installed Python 2.7 first using the Ububtu software Centre, then I went for Eclipse. I can run IDLE with no problems but still eclipse is not showing Python. I am using the same mechanism on Windows & it is working fine. I am not getting the Pydev option so that I could select the interpreter at all.

Comment: I edited my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your version of Java. That will allow python to run.

Java 7 (or 1.7) is required to run the latest pyDev plugin updates.

Answer (score 0):

Manualy download zip file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/) and extract it, like suggested on [PyDev install web site](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html). Then go to directory where you installed Eclipse (default is `/home/username/eclipse`) and copy exctracted content into `eclipse/dropins` folder and restart Eclipse. Worked for me on `Kubuntu 18.04` and `Eclipse 4.7`