# PyDev not found in Eclipse Kepler Eclipse says it's correctly installed

Tags: installation, python, eclipse

I suppose it's a similar problem as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230601/eclipse-not-showing-pydev-in-preferences/377927), but I was asked to file a separate question, because my problem is Python-3-related.

Situation: Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Python 3.2.3, installing Eclipse (Kepler) and PyDev.

Problem: Cannot configure PyDev, cannot create Python project. Same procedure on Windows 7 works fine.

I followed the guidelines at http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html, but neither "Install New Software" nor via the "Eclipse Marketplace" did work, i.e. I don't see any Python or PyDev entry in Window/Preferences. Well, it seems to be installed, because Eclipse says "already installed", if I try to install it again.

From the command line python is working:

```
$ python
Python 3.2.3 (default, Sep 25 2013, 18:22:43) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I tried to link `python` to `python2.7` in `/usr/bin` but with no effort.

Does anyone have an idea yet?

**EDIT:** `java -version` says "1.6.0_27"

[image: Eclipse Marketplace with PyDev installed]

Comment: I got exactly the same problem on Mac OS X 10.8.5 and Python 2.7.6, so i guess it is a problem related to eclipse / pydev more than Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu and MacOS both base on Debian, so there may be a connection indeed. A friend recommended to take a look at the Java version. It's 1.6.0_27 here. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: do you have any broken downloads??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and configurations as yours. After switch to Java v1.7 using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

First you might not see PyDev perspective but just import/create a Python project and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can install java7 to get PyDev v3 to work and retain your current Java install version and not affect your current set up by specifying which JVM Eclipse should use using the command line -vm option.

[All is explained here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19838294/911550